# Multiple Update in MySQL through one query with multiple conditions in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to create one query using case condition with some additional conditions to avoid looping it. Idk where the problem is.

Code here:

```
Using MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Using MyCommand As New MySqlCommand()
            With MyCommand
                .Connection = MysqlConn
                .CommandText = "update beardata.results set team = case rownumber" & _
                                             "when 1 then @par1" & _
                                             "when 2 then @par1" & _
                                             "when 3 then @par1" & _
                                             "when 4 then @par1" & _
                                             "when 5 then @par1" & _
                                             "end" & _
                                             "where bnumber = @bnum and hraciden = @pd and league = @lm and rownumber in (1,2,3,4,5)"
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", Team1Box.SelectedItem.ToString)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@bnum", currentButton.Tag)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pd", Convert.ToInt16(playDayBox.SelectedItem))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lm", LeagueBox.SelectedItem.ToString)
            End With
            Try
                MysqlConn.Open()
                MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MysqlConn.Close()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                MysqlConn.Dispose()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

Can you point me in the right direction about the commandtext? Or suggest another solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually looked at the contents of that `CommandText` after that code executes?  I'll wager not.  Why was that not the first thing you did?  Look at the SQL you're executing, not the code that builds that SQL.  It's not what you think it is.  I suggest that you use an XML literal to create that SQL code.

Comment: Thanks a Lot! I made breakpoint in debugger, looked at that commandtext and knew that these missing spaces made fine mess of the whole command. I was tired yesterday and didnt notice such stupid mistake :/